# how is data is being passed from child to parent in react?

Tags: reactjs

How is onSubmit which is AddExpense component receving data from ExpenseForm ???

data cannot be sent from child to parent isnt it ???

I am very confused about sending data between the components ???

AddExpensePage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ExpenseForm from './ExpenseForm'
import { addExpense} from '../actions/expenses'

const AddExpensePage = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Add expense</h1>
            <ExpenseForm
            onSubmit={(expense)=>{
                props.dispatch(addExpense(expense))
                //redirect to page without refrshing
                props.history.push('/')
            }} 
            />
       </div>
    )
}

export default connect()(AddExpensePage)
```

ExpenseForm.js

```
onSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!this.state.description||!this.state.amount){
        this.setState(()=>{
            return {
                error:'please provide a description and amount'
            }
        })
    }else{
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                error: ''
            }
        })
        this.props.onSubmit({
            description:this.state.description,
            amount:parseFloat(this.state.amount,10)*100,
            createdAt:this.state.createdAt.valueOf(), //createdAt is a moment object
            note:this.state.note 
        })

    }

}
```

Comment: I see you're using `redux`, so that means you have a `store` which holds the whole value that can be accessed by any components. You can have a look at `useSelector` in `redux` to select the value you want either from parent or child component you want. Ref: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks

Comment: my question is how this.props.onSubmit({}) sending data from ExpenseForm to AddExpense. redux part i understood

Comment: you're doing it correctly, passing an object via `this.props.onSubmit`, this object will be passed to `onSubmit` in `<AddExpensePage />` as `expense` , that's exactly passing data flow from child to parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data to parent components thanks to props that are functions, which is the case for `onSubmit` in your code.

In your case, the data is passed to the `onSubmit` prop in the form of an object. See `ExpenseForm.js`:

```js
this.props.onSubmit({
    description:this.state.description,
    amount:parseFloat(this.state.amount,10)*100,
    createdAt:this.state.createdAt.valueOf(), //createdAt is a moment object
    note:this.state.note 
})
```

This data is contained in the `expense` parameter of the `onSubmit` function. See `AddExpensePage.js`:

```js
<ExpenseForm
    onSubmit={(expense)=>{
        props.dispatch(addExpense(expense))
        //redirect to page without refrshing
        props.history.push('/')
    }} 
/>
```

In other words, `expense` here is an object with the following properties: `description`, `amount`, `createdAt`, and `note` because of what is passed as an argument to `this.props.onSubmit` in `ExpenseForm.js`.

Does that help?

This React documentation page will give you plenty of details on how props work: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component.

Answer (score 0):

use can not pass data child component to parent component use redux to pass  data to any where means child to parent and parent to child components